# SocketException when there is no internet connection

Tags: java, android, sockets, exception, tcp

I'm programming an application which opens socket in service and sends some data to server and also listens for incoming data. Problem of course appears when connection with internet is lost on android device.

Here is code snippet where i get

> java.net.SocketException: recvfrom failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed
>   out)

```
try{
        mSocket = new Socket("xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx", xxxxx);
        out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(mSocket.getOutputStream())), true);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(mSocket.getInputStream()));
        String s;
        while((s = in.readLine())!= null){ //here error of course
            ...
        }
        mSocket.close();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Error is thrown when internet connection is lost and `BufferedReader` try to 
`readLine()`. How to avoid this and why is it of course?

**UPDATE**

Error didn't bother me until I tryed to do next scenario:
1) run socket with wifi turned on
2) turn on also mobile data
3) turned off wifi

When wifi is turned off error occourse, but i'm connected to internet through mobile data, so I would like continu to listen on socket without error. Is this possible and how?

Comment: don't loose internet connection...? isn't this obvius that when you don't have connection then there will be some kind of `Exception` thrown? you should catch it like you do now and print info about lost connection for user

Comment: please try, while (in.ready()) {
    s = in .readLine();
   ...
}

Comment: I updated post.

Comment: There is no 'problem' here to solve. You are correctly receiving an exception when the connection is lost. Thisnisnexsctly what should happen. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: Did you see update? Exception occourse if I'm connected to internet, but not with same type of connection with which was socket started.

Comment: The update makes no difference. You are correctly being told about a problem which does exist. Errors may not bother you, but they sure bother the socket. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: @EJP I respect you, and your answers on stackoverflow really helped me a loooot, but i hate those comments when you're saying "Unclear what you're asking", cuz honestly, this answer helped me find a solution in like 10minutes...

Answer (score 1):

What you should do is reconnect a new socket in your catch block. The original connection is now gone, and I don't know a way of "seamlessly" swapping it.

```
try {
  mSocket = new Socket("xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx", xxxxx);
  ...
} catch(Exception e){
    try {
      mSocket = new Socket("xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx", xxxxx);
      ...
    } catch (Exception e2) {
      // OK you really lost connectivity at this point, tell the user.
    }
}
```

Comment: Connection isn't really lost, just type of connection is changed from wifi to mobile data.

Comment: As I said, I don't think you can swap connection types like that. I believe TCP will actually kill the connection, so a new `Socket` is needed.

Comment: @DomenJakofčič You are mistaken. The connection is lost. The socket is broken and must be closed.

Comment: Thanx both for answers, I didn't totally understand how this work. So now I add in catch block next code if(networkAvailable){ stopService(); startService()} and it works fine. I'm aware that there are some edge cases scenarios but I will try handle them.